# Find the local drive

Tags: javascript

I need to locate the local hard drive on Windows or *nix.

I have the following code for finding the local hard drive:

```
File f = new File("/");
Long freeSpace = f.getFreeSpace();
Long totalSpace = f.getTotalSpace();
```

The data doesn't seem to be correct. Is the right way to locate the local hard drive?

**Update:**

After another look at the data, the code seems to be correct. Sorry for this should-not-asked question.

Comment: What do you mean by "locate the local hard drive"?  What do you want to do with this information?

Comment: As shown in the code, I need to find the disk space.

Comment: Your code looks fine - What doesn't work?

Comment: Ok.  But note that "local drive" is maybe difficult to define.  There may be 0, 1, or many "local" drives.

Comment: @assylias I have another look at the data. It is right. I need some coffee in the morning. Sorry for this nonsense question.